# Irreducibility of linear sections of the commuting variety

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, matrices, commuting-variety

The irreducibility of the commuting variety $\{(A,B) \in \mathcal{M}_{n}(\mathbb{C})^2, \ AB = BA \}$ is well-known (see for instance [On Dominance and Varieties of Commuting Matrices](https://doi.org/10.2307/1970336) by Gerstenhaber). I am interested in the irreducibility of some special linear sections of the commuting varieties. Namely, let $W_1$, $W_2$ be two $k$-dimensional subspaces of $\mathbb{C}^n$ ($n$ and $k$ are fixed). Is the variety:
$$ \{(A,B)\in \mathcal{M}_{n}(\mathbb{C})^2, \ AB = BA, \ W_1 \subset \operatorname{Ker}(A), \ W_2 \subset \operatorname{Ker}(B) \}$$
known to be irreducible? Or perhaps are there examples where it is not?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is already reducible in the toy case $n=2, k=1$ where $W_1, W_2 \subseteq \mathbb{C}^2$ are two distinct lines. Without loss of generality, have them be spanned by the standard basis vectors respectively, so that
$$A = \begin{bmatrix}0 & a_{12} \\ 0 & a_{22} \end{bmatrix}, \quad
B = \begin{bmatrix}b_{11} & 0 \\ b_{21} & 0 \end{bmatrix}.$$
The equation $AB = BA$ now reads
$$\begin{bmatrix}a_{12}b_{21} & 0 \\ a_{22}b_{21} & 0 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}0 & b_{11}a_{12} \\ 0 & b_{21}a_{12} \end{bmatrix}.$$
(As you can see, $AB=BA=0$.) But we have
$$(a_{22}b_{21}, a_{12}b_{21}, a_{12}b_{11}) = (a_{22},a_{12}) \cap (a_{12},b_{21}) \cap (b_{11},b_{21})$$
of ideals in four variables, so there are three irreducible components of dimension $2$ here.

In contrast, in the case $W_1 = W_2$, the equation $AB=BA$ instead has the form of the single equation $ab'=a'b$, which is not only irreducible, but of a different dimension and degree.

So I imagine it's complicated in general, depending on $n,k$ and $\dim(W_1 \cap W_2)$. I wouldn't be surprised if there's a story here similar to Springer fibers, which vary in dimension and reducibility, but in a very nice way.

**edit**:
Investigations in Macaulay2 for the case $n=4, k=2$ give the following:

- If $W_1 + W_2 = \mathbb{C}^4$, then the variety has six irreducible components (two of dimension 9, four of dimension 8).
- If $\dim(W_1 \cap W_2) = 1$, then the variety has eight irreducible components (three of dimension 9 and five of dimension 8).
- If $W_1 = W_2$, then the variety has two irreducible components, both of dimension 10, but with different degrees of generators.

Comment: Thank you for this interesting example. I am especially intestested in the case $W_1 = W_2$. Do you know any reference on that matter?

Comment: I just thought through that example myself, but you might try the hyperdeterminant book by Gelfand, Kapranov and Zelevinsky, or in Weyman’s book on cohomology of vector bundles and syzygies. Both have various similar-seeming calculations about spaces of matrices.

Comment: Followup: I tried the case $n=4, k=2$ on Macaulay2. If $W_1 + W_2 = \mathbb{C}^4$, I found there are six irreducible components (two of dimension 9, four of dimension 8). If $\dim(W_1 \cap W_2) = 1$, I found eight irreducible components, of which three of dimension $9$ and five of dimension $8$. If $W_1 = W_2$, I found two irreducible components, both of dimension $10$ but with different degrees of generators. So in all cases, reducible and seemingly complicated.

Comment: fascinating! Can you edit your answer to include this computation? I will then accept your answer.

Comment: OK, I have done so.